# Executing python class code located in folders

Tags: python, scripting

I currently have a folder structure like this:

```
.
├── main.py
└── parent.py
└── classes
    └── subclass1.py
    └── subclass2.py
    └── subclass3.py
```

Each of the `subclass`es are a subclass of `parent`, and parent is an abstract class. The subclasses need to execute some functions like `mix()` and `meld()`, and each of these subclasses must implement `mix()` and `meld()`.

I would like to write `main.py` such that the functions in each of the subclasses are executed, without me having to `import` their files into my program. That is, I'd like something akin to the following to happen:

```
def main():
    # Note that I don't care about the order of which these
    for each subclass in the sources folder:
        execute `mix()` and `meld()`
        # Note that I don't mind which order the order 
        # of which the subclasses' functions are invoked.
```

Is there any way I could get this to happen?

Essentially, what I want to do is drop a bunch of classes into the `classes` folder, with only `mix()` and `meld()` defined, and let this program run wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried this, but I *think* it does what you're asking for:

```
import os
import imp
import runpy

package = 'classes'

_, path, _ = imp.find_module(package)
for m in os.listdir(path):
    if m.endswith('.py'):
        runpy.run_module(
            package + '.' + os.path.splitext(m)[0], 
            run_name="Mix_Meld"
        )
```

Then, inside of your subclasses, you can write:

```
if __name__ == 'Mix_Meld':
    ClassName.mix()
    ClassName.meld()
```

This may result in additional code, granted, but if you ever need to stop the execution in one of the files, doing so is just a matter of commenting out that part of the code.

Another advantage is extensibility and polymorphism; if you need to run the code a bit differently for each one of these modules in the future, you only have to change the behaviour in the specific modules. The callee (`main.py`) will remain oblivious to those changes and continue calling the modules the usual way.

Comment: Wow, today I learned `runpy` was a thing. Thank you very much.

Comment: @hlin117 No problem. I also fixed a small mistake-- I was missing the dot operator (`.`) between the package name (`classes`) and the modules names.

Comment: I actually hit an error on the line `imp.find_module(package)`. I had to use this stackoverflow suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/2014591

Comment: @hlin117 That's normal. It really depends on how you've set up your environment variables and/or how you've organized your project structure.  As you can see in the docs for [imp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html), when you don't supply a path argument, `find_module` uses _"the list of directory names given by sys.path"_. I don't usually modify sys.paths, personally, but it is a valid approach in certain cases.

Comment: @hlin117 Just as a quick addition to that, you could have also (as I just alluded to) used `find_module` _as is_ by supplying that optional `path` argument. It's a bit cleaner IMO, but really it boils down to preference.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing from the subfolder in the `main.py` program file:

```
from glob import *
import os

for i in glob.glob(os.path.join('classes', '*.py')):
    __import__(i); className = i[:-3].capitalize()
    eval(className).mix(); eval(className).meld()
```

Comment: I could see why this works, but I was hoping to avoid the "eval" command. Is there a more pythonic way to execute this code?

Comment: I don't think so. As for the class name, I assumed it was the same at the file name.